# Swift 2 - Cant Loop UIView with Containing UITextField and Label

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swifty-json

I am using swiftyjson to grab some json data and display it in a message box UITextView and UILabel. I have a for LOOP but i can not get the contents to loop inside of my UIScrollview.

I am creating a message box that displays username, date and message inside of a UIView.

My code:

```
for (_, subJson) in json["messageData"] {
   self.outterMessageBox.hidden = false
   self.usernameBox.text = subJson["user"].string
   self.messageTXTBOX?.text = subJson["message"].string
   self.dateBox.text = subJson["datetime"].string
}
```

And this is the output. Looks fine, just will not loop inside of my scroll view. I've also tried to programmatically create these views with the below code... It still does not loop. What can I be doing wrong?

[image: message box]

Programmatically Created Views (i've displays only one iteration of the message box and does not loop as expected).

```
let myField: UITextField = UITextField (frame: self.ms.bounds)
    myField.text = subJson["message"].string! + "\n"
    self.ms.addSubview(myField)

let myNameLabel: UILabel = UILabel (frame: self.nm.bounds);
    myNameLabel.text = subJson["user"].string
    self.nm.addSubview(myNameLabel)

let myDt: UILabel = UILabel (frame: self.dt.bounds)
    myDt.text = subJson["datetime"].string
    self.dt.addSubview(myDt)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, why not use a tableview?  Second I don't see anywhere in your loop where you are creating a new view for each iteration and adding it to the scrollview

Comment: Hmmm... Im new to swift didnt think about a table view but i will give it a try.

Comment: Im not sure how to add the new views to the scrollview? It looks like it is o ly adding one and not looping

Comment: That is because you are just changing the values of your properties with the last object in your json

Comment: @EridB can you give me advice on how to add it to my scrollview? i dont want to change values i need to display the messages on top of the other

Comment: @MizAkita you can use either tableView by creating a reusable cell which contains your view (Best case) or you can create a custom view and reuse it to add it over the scrollView.